# UWP Cordova - Not able to run the app after creation of appxupload build

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, uwp, visual-studio-cordova, appxmanifest

Currently working on cordova windows 10 UWP mobile apps. Initially it was working fabulously. After all the changes, tried to create appxupload build. It got created successfully. But same time I had configured my app with windows app store. After this change, my appxmanifest file got changed. It got replaced with app store details.

[image]

With previous changes it was working, but after creation of appxupload file everything got changed.
Now I can see only splash screen. After splash screen I am getting white screen.

[image]

Accordingly I changed start page path also based on package name. Still I am getting same issue. May I know is there any way I can run the app on device successfully with appxmanifest file changes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I resolved the issue doing below changes..

I added below things in config.xml

```
<preference name="WindowsStoreIdentityName" value="12225TOTO42.3355241V9C2T6" />
<preference name="WindowsStorePublisherName" value="CN=9985D2C8-IUI5-4272-TOTO-EBR6FE26877A" />
```

After that I ran below command in Command Prompt

```
cordova build windows --release --prod --arch="arm"
```

That's it. It solved my issue.